# Cannot extend a class, extra methods undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-class

Suppose I have the following class:

```
import EventEmitter from 'event-emitter';

export default class SharedChannel extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(opts) {
    super();
    console.log('SharedChannel constructor');
  }

  send(event, data) {
    console.log('SharedChannel send');
  }
}
```

In my application, I try to use that class:

```
import SharedChannel from './lib/SharedChannel';
const channel = new SharedChannel();
channel.send('sessionData', 'Some session data goes here');
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: channel.send is not a function

Methods from the EventEmitter class do work, but my `send` method does not.  I can, for example, call `channel.emit()`.  Also, I am able to access class methods from within that class constructor.  For example, I can call `channel.send()` right after `super()`.  I'm able to hack around it by calling `this.send = function() { ...` in the constructor, but of course, this should not be necessary.

This application is being built with Webpack and Babel.  In my `webpack.config.js`, I have the following Babel rule:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
    }
  }
}
```

In `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Versions for packages:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta",
"webpack": "^4.16.5",
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
```

Any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing the API of `EventEmitter`. It is not meant to be used as a parent class, it is a mixin. If we look at [the usage documentation](https://github.com/medikoo/event-emitter#usage) for instance:

```
var ee = require('event-emitter');

var MyClass = function () { /* .. */ };
ee(MyClass.prototype);
```

Calling the `ee` function with the `MyClass.prototype` mixes the event emitter logic onto the class prototype. Similarly, in your example you'd want

```
import EventEmitter from 'event-emitter';

export default class SharedChannel {
  constructor(opts) {
    console.log('SharedChannel constructor');
  }

  send(event, data) {
    console.log('SharedChannel send');
  }
}
EventEmitter(SharedChannel.prototype);
```